# Error occurring while generating signed apk in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

This is coming while I am generating the signed apk.

```
Could not download groovy-all.jar (org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.12): No cached version available for offline mode.
```

Comment: That's an error in your gradle sources. Do you have a working internet connection?

Comment: disable offline mode.

Comment: Yes I have - Hed Shafran

Comment: How can I do so   - KuLdip PaTel

Comment: @PoojaPachchigar In your Android Studio go to File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle and uncheck offline work and apply the changes

Answer (score 2):

This works for me.

In `build.gradle` (module:app) of Android studio,

add

```
dependencies {testImplementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.15'}
```

…and sync the project.

Refer this link for more details: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/groovy_plugin.html